# execjs not finding node on yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, execjs, osx-yosemite

I updated my mac for Yosemite yesterday, since then my rails can't compile the Javascript, with the error:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Home#index
Showing /Users/wilkerlucio/Development/hpb/app/views/layouts/application.html.slim where line #35 raised:

sh: node: command not found
```

I already tried to re-install Node.js, but no lucky...

Answer (score 0):

Try using [therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) for Javascript runtime. Add

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

in Gemfile. It embeds V8 JavaScript interpreter into Ruby.